# bash: is there any kind of buffer for last visited paths?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

look at this steps:

```
:~$ cd programacion/
:~/programacion$ cd sports/
:~/programacion/sports$ cd src/
:~/programacion/sports/src$ cd Sports/
:~/programacion/sports/src/Sports$ cd PlatformBundle/
:~/programacion/sports/src/Sports/PlatformBundle$ cd Entity/
:~/programacion/sports/src/Sports/PlatformBundle/Entity$ cd /
:/$
```

being in this moment in the last prompt, is there any way to go directly to `programacion/sports/src/Sports/PlatformBundle/Entity` since it is the last path i have visited?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following shortcut to the last directory:

`cd -`

For example:

```
kbrandt@alpine:~$ pwd
/home/kbrandt
kbrandt@alpine:~$ cd src
kbrandt@alpine:~/src$ cd -
/home/kbrandt
kbrandt@alpine:~$ cd -
/home/kbrandt/src
kbrandt@alpine:~/src$
```

Another option would be to use the `$OLDPWD` shell variable.

Comment: The last visited directory is also stored in the environment variable `OLDPWD`.

Answer (score 3):

bash's `pushd` and `popd` do what you want, and more.

```
$ help pushd

$ help popd
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also download the [Teleport](http://www.devdaily.com/linux/linux-teleport-command-cd-improved) script, analogous to bash history, but for directories.